# Query returning syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 3 tables with various columns:

```
tableA = id(PK) & name columns
tableB = id(PK), A_ID(foreign key to tableA), name, address, etc columns
tableC = id(PK), A_ID(foreign key to tableA), name columns
```

I’m trying to use the following query to retrieve values from certain columns within all tables based on tableA name = ‘something’, but always returning syntax errors.

```
“SELECT tableA.name, tableB.name, tableB.address, tableC.name FROM 
tableA, tableB, tableC JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.A_ID JOIN tableC 
ON tableA.id = tableC.A_ID WHERE tableA.name = ‘something’”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ms Access requires you to specify the type of join: `INNER`; `LEFT`; or `RIGHT`.  Access does not recognize just `JOIN` as a synonym for `INNER JOIN`.

A query which includes more than one join requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause.

I also changed your quote characters to plain `"` and `'`.  The sample query included type-setting quotes.  I don't know if they are present in the actual SQL, but I would avoid them.

```sql
SELECT tableA.name, tableB.name, tableB.address, tableC.name
FROM 
    (tableA
    INNER JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.id = tableB.A_ID)
    INNER JOIN tableC
    ON tableA.id = tableC.A_ID
WHERE tableA.name = 'something'
```

If you have the full version of Access available, use the query designer to set up the joins.  The designer knows the syntax rules which keep the db engine happy.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem, no parantheses in my join.  I changed it to INNER JOIN, but was using JOIN because I had read that 'joins were inner joins by default. join statements are the same as inner join statements'....Learning C# by Jesse Liberty.

Comment: That is true with many databases but not Access.  Your life will be easier if you can use the Access query designer.  If you don't have Access, it might be worthwhile to install an evaluation version.

Comment: I'm running this from a winforms project and using a OleDbDataReader to retrieve records.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove tables from `from` statement if you want to use `join` syntax

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableB.name, tableB.address, tableC.name 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.A_ID 
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableA.id = tableC.A_ID 
WHERE tableA.name = 'something'
```

I suggest you to use aliases, the code could be more readable:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, B.address, C.name 
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.A_ID 
INNER JOIN tableC C ON A.id = C.A_ID 
WHERE A.name = 'something'
```

Comment: Try with `INNER JOIN` as above.

Answer (score 0):

otherwise you could do it like:

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableB.name, tableB.address, tableC.name 
FROM tableA, tableB, tableC 
WHERE tableA.id = tableB.A_ID AND tableA.id = tableC.A_ID 
AND tableA.name = ‘something
```

Answer (score 0):

Parado's answer is correct..

Moreover you can simplify the length of the query by using aliases for the table names.. And it is good practice too..

select a.name, b.name, b.address
from tableA a
  join tableB b
    on a.id = b.A_ID